# nosliderUI - how to prevent user from dragging beyond 50%

Tags: javascript, jquery

http://refreshless.com/nouislider/

I'm using nouislider. Right now I have a range 0 to 100. What I want to do is to prevent the user from dragging the slide beyond 50%. When the slider is dragged to at least 50%, it should stop at 50%. From this link, http://refreshless.com/nouislider/events-callbacks/, I can do a jquery function callback.

```
 $("#slider1").on({
        slide: function(event, value) {
            if (value > 50){
                return false;
            }
        }
    });

    $('#slider1').noUiSlider({
        start: 0,
        step : 10,
        limit: 10,
        behaviour: 'snap',
        range: {
            min: 0,
            max: 100
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
 $("#slider1").on({
        slide: function(event, value) {
            if (value > 50){
                $("#slider1").val(50);
            }
        }
    });
```

This way, every time value > 50% it will set it back to 50%.